# Transition Post status not working

Tags: plugins, hooks

I have a plugin which uses the `transition_post_status` hook, to fire a custom function on post update. But I don't know why its not working.
Here is the code

```
 add_action('transition_post_status', 'pmc_update_notification',10,3);

function pmc_update_notification($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
echo 'function checkpoint 1';
$options = get_option('pmc_setting');
if($options['snpi'] != false && is_single()){
   if ( $old_status == 'publish' && $new_status == 'publish' ) {
  echo 'function checkpoint 2';
$post_title = get_the_title($post);
$post_url = get_permalink($post);
$message = __('Post updated','pmc').":\n";
$message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;

// Send notification
pmc_send($message);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: any error ? activate debug mode

Comment: Debug mode is activated but no error is showen

Comment: do you have called this function ? `wp_head`

Comment: No. Why should i ?

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Why a down vote?!

Comment: It wasn't from me :D but it's better to ask problems better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

It was the `is_single()` line.
It's not working because its outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to called this function in your `header.php` (your wp theme) :

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

And this one into your `Footer.php` :

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Because you are adding action to your Wordpress, so you have to call that function in your theme.

Comment: I am using this in a plugin, not a theme as i said in my question

Comment: I know, but this works when your them call that functions, without them, plugin won't work

Comment: Of course the theme calls that. I am using twenty twelve

Comment: @user2761273 so, better to wait for others answer.

Comment: Ok, but anyway thanks for your help